# Intellij IDEA not respecting maven settings

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I want to run my junit tests, IntelliJ IDEA tries to resolve junit-platform-launcher-1.5.1 and it fails. My network is restricted and I do not have access to the internet and it should fetch it from our Artifactory server.

However, although I have set the correct settings in the project settings and also in the pom (When I run, e.g., mvn clean verify it works fine), IntelliJ tries to fetch them from repo1.maven.org (according to its log file) and it fails. Maybe IntelliJ has a hidden internal maven which does not respect the settings I have provided for the project. An strange thing about it is that it sometimes runs and sometimes tries to resolve the dependency and fails. How can I solve the problem?

The maven that my project, MAVEN_HOME, and default mvn command of the system use has a settings.xml like this:

```
...
<proxies>
</proxies>

<servers>
</servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>mvn</id>
        <name>...</name>
        <url>...</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <localRepository>...</localRepository>
                <id>mvn</id>
                <name>...</name>
                <url>...</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <actirveProfile>dev</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
...
```

Comment: Maybe the environmental variable on your computer and IntelliJ IDEA are using different MAVEN_HOME ?

Comment: take a look at your Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven. check it is the correct installation of maven, and the correct user settings file.

Comment: @EmreAcar Both MAVEN_HOME and the default mvn command point to the maven I use for my project.

Comment: Of course they do, what about the setting @PaulRdt mentioned ?

Comment: @PaulRdt That's where I have set the desired maven, but the intellij still tries to fetch from central. I'll add some more details to the question now.

Comment: Make sure you have correct profile activated in Maven tool window. May be related https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96241 Try to define the repository configuration in pom.xml file directory. Make also sure to check with the version from  
 https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Answer (score 6):

This might happen due to Intellij Idea update.
After this update my maven home path has been changed to "Bundled (Maven 3)", which differs from Maven version I get from cmd (`mvn -v`).

Changing *maven home path* to the Maven version (Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven), which corresponds to `mvn -v` version, solved the issue in my case.

Comment: it works for me :) thanks. For other users, don't forget to add your custom "settings.xml" file to this "~/.m2/setting.xml" path. Or you can choose custom "setting.xml" path in maven configuration screen.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the settings @Paul Rdt mentioned:
[image: settings screenshot]

Perhaps your pom inherits a repositories setting from a parent pom that overrides the settings?

Answer (score 0):

In Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools -> Maven, have something like this:

[image]

Where you explicitly point to settings.xml file where you have correct settings (ones overriding default maven repo with your artifactory repo) and override any default IntelliJ would use (tick the box!).